# How to use the client storage, redux store and SQL backend together in Angular?

Tags: angular, redux, indexeddb, ngrx

I'm trying to use the [cache-aside](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside) pattern in an [Angular](https://angular.io/) app. I have a `MS SQL DB` Backend from where I read `products` data. I use [@ngrx store](https://github.com/ngrx/store), and that's where I keep the state of the `products` after I read from the `MS SQL DB` Backend.

Into this mix, I added [@ngrx db](https://github.com/ngrx/db) to cache the `products` data. The purpose is to read from the `IndexedDB` after browser is closed and open again, so to avoid a trip to the server.

In this [cache-aside](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/architecture/patterns/cache-aside) pattern, I see a cache and the server. In my app, that is `IndexedDB` and the `MS SQL DB`. I don't know how to use the `@ngrx redux store` in this mix.

1. When the application starts, should I read all the state from the cache (`IndexedDB`) to the redux store, and access the state from the redux store?
2. Or should I replace the redux store and use only cache (`IndexedDB`)?
3. Should I update the `@ngrx redux store` or the `IndexedDB` first if I have to update/write an entry?
4. Is using both the `IndexedDB` and the `@ngrx store` inefficient because of the duplication of the data (one in memory and one on the disk)?

Comment: You should use [@ngrx/effects](https://github.com/ngrx/effects) as retrieving and storing from the cache or your db are both side effects to the store data. You can create a natural flow through dispatched actions that write to the cache as a side effect when they are writing to the store.  There is also an example of retrieving data on bootstrap https://gist.github.com/btroncone/a6e4347326749f938510#implementing-a-meta-reducer

Comment: The link that you provided is for ```meta-reducer```. To me it is an observer pattern which extend the functionality of an existing object/function. I think what you are suggesting is ```pre-middleware``` as reading from cache and ```post-middleware``` as saving to the database. I don't know how this can be solved with ```@ngrx effects```. Should a ```meta-reducer``` wrap an ```@ngrx effect```?